# $_GET and $_POST not working

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php and am trying some very simple tests to get started.

I seem to be unable to get any values from $_GET.

This test.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<html>
<body><h1>GET test</h1><p>
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>
</p></body></html>
```

produces the following when called with `http://my.url/test.php?aValue=A&bValue=B`

```
<html>
<body><h1>GET test</h1><p>
Array
(
)
</p></body></html>
```

I do not have write access to /etc/php.ini on the server, but check register_globals and it is off.

I have also tried using $_POST method, but this also doesn't work.

PHP version: PHP 5.1.6

Comment: Try `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. That should give you the raw query string (aValue=A&bValue=B in your example). If that is giving you the right value, it's probably a configuration error

Comment: Are you calling this from the command line or from a browser? The first line of code would seem to suggest that you're also accessing it via the command line.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey: echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] worked, so now I just have to track down the config error.
Thanks gabriel: I'm calling it from a browser, but I found that unless the shebang line was there, I got a 500 error.

Comment: Seems like PHP is installed as CGI then. Can you try and verify this?
Since you don't have write access to php.ini I take it the server isn't yours? Have you verified with the 'ISP' whether they know about this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The $_GET and $_POST variables are only available if `track_vars` is turned on.

As of PHP version 4.0.3 that is always automatically enabled.

Can you check your PHP version and also check the value of `track_vars` in php.ini?

It would also be helpful if you check phpinfo();

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Check for

- something called `--enable-track-vars`, which should be present.
- `_SERVER["argv"]`, should contain an array if you pass vars via a GET request.
- also "Loaded Configuration File" should resolve to the file you think it is.

source: [PHP: Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: Thanks nash. The PHP version is PHP 5.1.6. I checked php.ini and there was no setting of track_vars. There were some comments about how it is on by default though. I tried phpinfo() and it looks like it's right ( --enable-track-vars was in there).