# GET not working in PHP

Tags: php

I can't for the life of me figure out why my attempts at using $_GET are not working.
As near as I can tell, I'm using it correctly, as I've used it in the past.

The link seems to be formatted correctly

```
<a href="script.php?variable=value">Value</a>
```

since I receive the correct information in the URL:

```
localhost.com/script.php?variable=value
```

but neither simply using:

```
$var = $_GET['variable'];
```

or using either of these two:

```
if (!isset($_GET['variable'])) {
    $var = $_GET['variable'];
}

if (isset($_GET['variable'])) {
    $var = $_GET['variable'];
}
```

nothing I do seems to be working, does anyone have any suggestions as to what to look out for?

Comment: Error or just empty string?

Comment: post results for `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: Do you get the same result if using `$_REQUEST['variable']`?

Comment: It's possible that the request is being rewritten by something like .htaccess (without the [QSA] flag). You can also check out the value of the http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order setting, which can disable certain superglobals.

Comment: `localhost.com` that's a virtual host, right? then you might like to check your VS config (i'm not a server admin so i suck at it :D)

Comment: Watch this may it will be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993730/get-not-working

Comment: try see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736602/get-and-post-not-working

Comment: @J0HN I would say empty string, but it seems my attempts at using echo does nothing, simply a blank screen

Comment: @Dagon it seems my attempts at using var_dump also does nothing, simply a blank screen

Comment: Check that there's a `G` in [`variables_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) in your php.ini. Or run `echo ini_get('variables_order');`

Comment: @Ejay, thanks for the pointer, but I more or less put that there as an example, its not really my localhost

Comment: Sounds to me like .htaccess could be rewriting it. Or, by any chance, are you using php shorthand tags (<? instead of <?php) with the `short_open_tag` disabled?

Comment: @henasraf you had it there, thanks alot

Comment: figured it out the .htaccess was rewriting the value